# Concept of satan

Tags: shaitan

I am confused as to what exactly satan means in Islam.
Is satan the evil deeds and thoughts that we do and that come to us because of the free will that has been given to us by Allah SWT or is satan an entity that's created by Allah SWT? Because we keep on hearing the names of satan like Iblees in Islam here and there, who are they then? It is said that it is satan that feeds ill thoughts into our minds. Please clarify on this.